# nearest month end in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Hi I want to find the nearest month end for a date column in R.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

```
dt<-data.frame(orig_dt=as.Date(c("1997-04-01",
      "1997-06-29"
)))


dt<-dt %>% mutate(modified_dt="Nearest_month_end_date")
```

ie 1997-04-01 should change to 1997-03-31 and 1997-06-29 should change to 1997-06-30.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(lubridate)
dt<-dt %>% mutate(modified_dt=round_date(orig_dt, unit="month")-days(1))

#Output
> dt
     orig_dt modified_dt
1 1997-04-01  1997-03-31
2 1997-06-29  1997-06-30
```