# round_date() function returns floor_date instead of rounded date

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Using an example from a related issue: [nearest month end in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241283/nearest-month-end-in-r/54241387#54241387)

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dt<-data.frame(orig_dt=as.Date(c("1997-04-01","1997-06-29")))
dt %>% mutate(round_dt=round_date(orig_dt, unit="month"),
              modified_dt=round_date(orig_dt, unit="month")-days(1))
```

in one session I correctly get the rounded dates (R 4.0.0, Rcpp_1.0.4.6 loaded via a namespace)

```
     orig_dt   round_dt modified_dt
1 1997-04-01 1997-04-01  1997-03-31
2 1997-06-29 1997-07-01  1997-06-30
```

in another session I get floor instead of round (different machine, R 4.0.2, Rcpp not loaded via a namespace)

```
     orig_dt   round_dt modified_dt
1 1997-04-01 1997-04-01  1997-03-31
2 1997-06-29 1997-06-01  1997-05-31
```

I think it could be related to Rcpp , as earlier I got an error message

```
Error in C_valid_tz(tzone) (rscrpt.R#27): function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
Show stack trace
```

Although I am not getting the error anymore, the values are different and I wonder why/how to fix it without going through complete reinstallation.

Comment: it may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416435/rcpp-package-doesnt-include-rcpp-precious-remove. You could reinstall Rcpp and see.

Comment: Thank you!  `Rcpp` also made issues which turned out to be unrelated to the `round_date` issue, as answered below. I also updated `Rcpp` now, so should be all fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your issue in a vanilla R session.

```r
$ R --vanilla
> packageVersion("lubridate")
[1] ‘1.8.0’
> library("lubridate")
> round_date(x = as.Date("1997-06-29"), unit = "month")
[1] "1997-06-01"
```

It seems to be a bug in `round_date`, introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/commit/f4a4e426588729c0b781613ddc0fa688aaf29b68#diff-6530cdec4c90e2f31d664264eb6d626ea1f827711403431a33f4afe27c3d8165). Prior to the commit, the body of `round_date` contained:

```r
above <- unclass(as.POSIXct(ceiling_date(x, unit = unit, week_start = week_start)))
mid <- unclass(as.POSIXct(x))
below <- unclass(as.POSIXct(floor_date(x, unit = unit, week_start = week_start)))
```

Here, `below`, `mid`, and `above` are defined as the number of seconds from `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` to the month-floor of `x`, `x`, and the month-ceiling of `x`, respectively (more precisely, time `00:00:00` on those three Dates, in your system's time zone). Thus, `below < mid < above`, and `round_date` would compare `mid-below` to `above-mid` to determine which of `below` and `above` was closer to `mid`.

Since the commit, `mid` has been defined as

```r
mid <- unclass(x)
```

which is the number of *days* from `1970-01-01` to `x`. Now, `mid << below < above`, making `mid-below` negative and `above-mid` positive. As a result, `round_date` considers `below` to be "closer" to `mid` than `above`, and it incorrectly rounds `1997-06-29` down to `1997-06-01`.

I have reported the regression to the package maintainers [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/1008). I imagine that it will be fixed soon...

In the mean time, you can try reverting to an older version of `lubridate`, from before the commit, or using this temporary work-around:

```r
round_date_patched <- function(x, unit) {
  as.Date(round_date(as.POSIXct(x), unit = unit))
}
round_date_patched(x = as.Date("1997-06-29"), unit = "month") # "1997-07-01"
```

Comment: Thank you, for the detailed explanation, that is very helpful! - and for reporting the issue! Using an earlier `lubridate` version solved the issue (via `install_version("lubridate", version = "1.7.9", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`).  Hope it gets fixed soon!